# Should I have different tables for different user types

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm creating an app in blade, where I need two different user types. (Landlord and tenant).

I'm currently using the laravel auth, and I have a dropdown menu which lets a user select there type upon registration. I need the users to interact with eachother.

Should I have seperate models for the landlord, and the tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a different table? Just use a userType column and you're good! If you do go with two table structure, you will have to manage two different structure and need all your logics done twice...

Comment: That's the way I have it/ I just wanted to make sure, that this is the right way. Thank you

Comment: It's a pleasure, sometime just confirming with others is helpful ;)